# CSS3 Gradient horizontal rule with text

Tags: html, css, line, gradient

I am trying to create an horizontal rule with linear-gradient using CSS3. Also, i would like some text in the middle of the rule.

I tried something like that:

```
.strike {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.strike > span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.strike > span:before,
.strike > span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 9999px;
  height: 1px;
}
.strike > span:before {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 15px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, #333333 100%, #333333 0%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #333333 100%, #333333 0%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(right, #333333 100%, #333333 0%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #333333 100%, #333333 0%);
}
.strike > span:after {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: 15px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #333333 100%, #333333 0%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #333333 100%, #333333 0%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #333333 100%, #333333 0%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #333333 100%, #333333 0%);
}

<div class="strike">
    <span>text</span>
</div>`
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LLztqgbn/

As you can see, the gradient is not working on the left/right side.

Thanks

wILL

Comment: Looks fine on iPad. Which browser is this not working in?

Comment: You should include the non-prefixed version of linear-gradient for browsers that support it / future versions

Comment: @3rror404 I am on Firefox 33, MaxOSX 10.10 aka Yosemite. Not working either with the non-prefixed version of linear-gradient.

Comment: FF33 on Yosemite I see `---- text -----` Is that not correct?

Comment: @3rror404 Sorry, i wasn't very clear. A visual example of what i am trying to reproduce would be better. Look at the example #2 on this page: http://css-tricks.com/examples/hrs/
This is what i would like to do, but with the text in the midle as shown in my first attempt.

Comment: Ah right, I see. Well if you want the line to fade out at the ends you need to use rgba for your colour. Something like `background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(51,51,51,0) 0%,rgba(51,51,51,1) 100%);` but you still won't see the effect because your `:before` and `:after` are so wide! they are `9999px` so the start of the gradient is way off the edge of the window. Here is a modified fiddle showing the gradient but I had to shorten your lines: http://jsfiddle.net/LLztqgbn/2/

Comment: @3rror404 Thanks you very much! I took pieces of CSS on the net and i didn't realized this. I make senses now. I just changed the width: 9999px rule to width: 100% to fit all the available space, and the gradient is perfect.
Again, thank you.
Best regards.
wILL

Comment: Haha. Ok I may have just wasted my time writing an answer in that case :)

Comment: @3rror404 Absolutely not, i will definitevely try your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the width of your `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements. they are much wider than the window so you will never see the start if your gradient.

i would suggest reworking your CSS as follows:

Remove your `:after` element and move your `:before` to the parent element and modify as below:

```
.strike:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(51,51,51,0) 0%,rgba(51,51,51,1) 50%,rgba(51,51,51,0) 100%);

}
```

Give the parent a position:

```
.strike {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}
```

This will give you the following which I think is pretty close to what you are trying to acheive. It also simplies your code a little which is always a bonus!

```css
.strike {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}
.strike > span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
  background: #FFF;
}
.strike:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(51,51,51,0) 0%,rgba(51,51,51,1) 50%,rgba(51,51,51,0) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="strike">
    <span>text</span>
</div>
```